# -startNavigationWithSettings Always Start from first in MKMaps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, skmaps

I am using Skobbler Map for navigation,

I am save the rout to cache ,

```
[[SKRoutingService sharedInstance]saveRouteToCache:calculatedRouteInfo.routeID];
```

and get the rout from Cache,

```
[[SKRoutingService sharedInstance]loadRouteFromCache:calculatedRouteInfo.routeID];
```

Where calculatedRouteInfo.routeID is `SKRouteID`

It automatically calculate the rout but, After start the navigation it always start from From the first.  Can I save the current position and start from the current position.
I have given the navigation code ,

```
SKNavigationSettings *navSettings = [SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings];
navSettings.navigationType=SKNavigationTypeSimulation;
navSettings.distanceFormat=SKDistanceFormatMilesFeet;
self.mapView.settings.displayMode = SKMapDisplayMode3D;
[[SKRoutingService sharedInstance]startNavigationWithSettings:navSettings];
```

Comment: Hi Vineesh - I don't understand what the issue/question is

Comment: If I save a rout (that time in a particular place) then, load from cache can I start from the particular place itself (not need to start from first).

Comment: What are you trying to do, what is your scenario?

Comment: @Newbiec: When I travel into a rout I need to pause/Clear the rout in map (that time save the rout into cache). then, I want to start navigation from the paused location (w can get the rout from cache).

Answer (score 0):

Right now during simulation there is no support for pause/resume route (you can still "pause/resume" navigation while using your phone but you cannot simulate this from the simulator)

Comment: I am asking not about simulation, testing in simulator itself.